# How do I create a StackNavigator for two screens?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation to build my first react-native app. I have a home screen on which I want to have a sign up button.

In my router file, I have the following:

```
export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({

Home: {
  screen: Home
}, 
SignUp: {
  screen: SignUp
}

}, {
mode: 'modal',
headerMode: 'none',

}
);
```

Here is my Home.js file:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
    const buttons = ['SIGN IN', 'SIGN UP']
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state

    return (
        <View style={styles.logoContainer} >
            <Button
              raised    
              backgroundColor="#333"
              title='SIGN IN' />

            <Button
              raised
              onPress = {this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
              backgroundColor="#333"
              title='SIGN UP' />

        </View>
    );
}
```

}

In my index file, I render this RootNavigator component.

When I load up the simulator, the navigation goes to the Home screen but immediately animates to the SignUp screen.

I'm quite new to this but what I want to be able to do is have the home screen appear, and be able to navigate to the sign up screen when I click on the Sign Up button (which is why I have the Sign up screen in the StackNavigator).

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please add code from your Home screen. I'm guessing you put your navigate logic in wrong place

Comment: just edited to include Home.js code

Answer (score 0):

You are executing function rather than passing as a property. Parenthesizes execute functions.

This,

```
onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
```

should be like below

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that you need more navigators. You have defined your onPress as the result of `this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')` however what you need is a function handle.

Put the following there and it will work as you intended;

`() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')`